# Setting Spring AOP Logging in OSGi bundle on Apache Karaf

Tags: java, spring, osgi, spring-aop, apache-karaf

I am trying to set up `Spring AOP` logging in `OSGi` bundle which is deployed in `Apache Karaf`. This is related to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077274/use-spring-aop-in-osgi-bundle). The answer provided there didn't help me. If I add maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have to export a bunch of packages:

```
org.aspectj.lang.*,
org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.*,
org.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.*,
org.aspectj.runtime.internal.*,
org.aspectj.runtime.*,
org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.*,
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.*,
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.*,
org.aspectj.bridge.*,
org.aspectj.util.*,
org.aspectj.weaver.*,
com.bea.jvm.*,
```

While the last one `(com.bea.jvm.*)` is breaking everything down. When I am trying to start my bundle it gives me the missing requirement error and says that this package is missing. `(package=com.bea.jvm)`. But it is exported. Instead of above maven dependency I have also tried different others but the same issue.

What I am missing here? There aren't much of information on the internet related to `OSGi` and `AOP`. Can someone help me? I'm stuck here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I needed to install these bundles:

```
install http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/org.aspectj/com.springsource.org.aspectj.runtime/1.6.2.RELEASE/com.springsource.org.aspectj.runtime-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar
install http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/org.aspectj/com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver/1.6.2.RELEASE/com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar
```

And import `org.aopalliance.aop,` package into my bundle and everything worked. Also there is no need to export this bunch of `(org.aspectj)` packages.